# When exactly is type-casting needed?

Tags: java, casting

So long story short I've spent the last 2-3 days trouble shooting a bug in my graphing calculator that arose when I implemented a new window resize listener. The bug was when I resized my window slowly the functions wouldn't be transformed properly and if I moved it fast they would transform just fine. I looked at all of my formulas and algorithms and everything was spot on (the same as it was with my previous window resizing method). Whenever there was a change in width I'd take the difference it changed, divide it by 2 and move the graphs by that amount. Really simple.

```
double changeX = (newCanvasWidth - canvasWidth)/2;

double changeY = (newCanvasHeight - canvasHeight)/2;
```

This had worked fine and made all of the logical sense I needed to ignore this as the culprit for nearly 3 days. It was so innocent that I almost rewrote my entire program to try and fix this issue ranging from compensation algorithms to all new methods to predict these errors and fix them. It was becoming a nightmare and was incredibly annoying. Before giving up complete hope I decided to investigate the problem once again using a thorough trace of every single calculation related to this and outputting the results of these calculations and I found something odd. Whenever the difference between (newCanvasWidth - canvasWidth) was odd I was not getting the half at the end of the integer.

So if the difference between them was say 15, changeX would reflect 7. Most troubling is when the difference was 1, changeX would be 0.

Upon discovering this I of course tried the obvious thing and type casted the subtraction.

```
double changeX = (double)(newCanvasWidth - canvasWidth)/2;

double changeY = (double)(newCanvasHeight - canvasHeight)/2;
```

And lo and behold my issue was solved!

What I don't understand though is why this didn't happen automatically. Also if this is just something I'm going to have to make accommodations for all of the time where is the limit? Is there anyway to know when you're going to need to type cast simple calculations like this?

Comment: It's the `/2`. You want `/2.0`.

Comment: Rather than casting, I believe if you change `2` to `2.0`, it should work just fine as well.

Comment: what are type of newCanvasWidth,canvasWidth,newCanvasHeight and canvasHeight

Comment: All of them were integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't happening automatically because the calculation on the right-hand side (RHS) of the assignment, i.e. `(newCanvasHeight - canvasHeight)/2` takes place as a separate operation before the assignment to `changeY`.  Since all terms on the RHS are integers, the result is an integer with the decimal part truncated (not rounded), which is then stored as a double (so instead of `7.5` you get `7`, which is stored as `7.0`).  Since you were using a constant term on the RHS, you could make it a double (like @Clown suggested), thereby making the result of the calculation a double before it is stored.  If all terms on the RHS were variables, however, then you would cast.

So, yes, there is a way to know when you need to cast (or otherwise convert) in situations like these: when the most precise term of the RHS of the assignment is less precise than the LHS.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't automatically expand integral expressions to floating-point because it's very expensive computationally to do so, and because you can lose precision. Yes, if you have an integral value that you want divided into a non-integral quotient, you'll always need to tell Java (and C/C++) that. The Java Language Specification has [comprehensive rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) about what type of value a math expression is.

A shortcut when using a numeric literal like this is to make the literal a floating-point type:

```
double changeX = (newCanvasWidth - canvasWidth) / 2.0;
```

Comment: Do you really need the casting when you already divide by `2.0`?

Comment: @ClownOfTheJungle Copypasta. You've got the rep, so feel free to edit obvious brain farts like that!

Comment: Alright well this is pretty eye opening and even shocking that I've come this far in this project without noticing this error up til now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because `newCanvasWidth` and `canvasWidth` is declared as `int`'s you don't automatically get a decimal result when dividing with another whole number. If you don't want to cast you should have been using `2.0`. Integer division in Java always discard decimals, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: Am I safe to assume, despite the real answer, that int/int returns an int and int/double returns a double and of course double/int returns a double as well?

Comment: @rosscowar: It's worth noting that operations involving an integer type and `float` will yield `float`, even if the result cannot be accurately represented in `float` but could be accurately represented in `double`.  For example, 33554434/2.0 will yield 16777217.0 (type `double`) but 33554434/2.0f will yield 16777216.0f (type `float`); the compiler will not warn of the consequent loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

If the result has a chance of becoming a decimal number, for example when using division, you should always make sure the result is a double. Here you would cast when necessary. But generally speaking, you use type casting a lot more often in different contexts, such as going from `Object` to something else, or, as an even better example, when going from a `View` to a `TextView` in Android.